# Does Quran agree with Bible and Eastern theologies in that man is created in the image of God?

Tags: image, mankind, aqidah, prophet-adam

We know that the Quran affirms that man is the best creation of Allah. But, does the Quran go further to suggest that 'Man is made in the image and likeness of God' or the lesser 'man is made in the image of the universe' that is claimed by the Christian theology in the Bible and Eastern traditions like Hinduism? Here image is not necessarily a physical image or form.

Edit: There are some references in the Hadiths which suggests that Man is made in the image of God. Is this accepted as a genuine hadith by Islamic scholars?
The hadith “Allah created Adam in His/his image (`ala suratihi)” was narrated from Abu Hurayrah by both Bukhari and Muslim.

References:

Answer on [seekershub](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2009/08/16/what-does-the-narration-allah-created-adam-in-hishis-image-mean/).

[Al-futuhat al Makiyyah](https://books.google.com/books?id=r07M9CXZ_t8C&pg=PA249&lpg=PA249&dq=ala%20suratihi&source=bl&ots=cidOYku8G5&sig=cMzHso6jCTrefMM2fHi92waZQ8Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_g7CFpfjMAhXIHT4KHYdcAggQ6AEIMjAE#v=onepage&q=ala%20suratihi&f=false) of ibn 'Arabi

Comment: Does Allah have a form or formless? I've have heard different opinions on this from scholars.

Comment: @Naveen May I know the reason behind this question?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful https://islamqa.info/en/20652

Comment: @ARYK I am a self taught student on comparative theology. On the question of whether Allah has form, I have heard a lecture of Zakir Naik and some Salafi scholar say that Allah has a form, but should not be speculated upon by humans and will be revealed only in Jannat. Other scholar say Allah has no form. I want to know if the Quran or any reliable hadith passage gives a decisively statement about the form of Allah.

Comment: I recommend this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOiYKJaZLiE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely not. On the contrary, Islam says clearly that nothing is alike God, neither the man nor any thing else : " ليس كمثله شئ و هو السميع البصير "  Surat Alashura , Aya 11.

Comment: I guess Quran has the final word on this, but there is a hadith which differs as per the following link.
http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2009/08/16/what-does-the-narration-allah-created-adam-in-hishis-image-mean/
The hadith “Allah created Adam in His/his image (`ala suratihi)” was narrated from Abu Hurayrah by both Bukhari and Muslim.

Comment: One more reference. Adding an edit. 
https://books.google.com/books?id=r07M9CXZ_t8C&pg=PA249&lpg=PA249&dq=ala+suratihi&source=bl&ots=cidOYku8G5&sig=cMzHso6jCTrefMM2fHi92waZQ8Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_g7CFpfjMAhXIHT4KHYdcAggQ6AEIMjAE#v=onepage&q=ala%20suratihi&f=false

Comment: In such minute and delicate subjects, one should learn Arabic to be able to understand religious text in its original language . "ala suratihi" here means "with similar adjectives" not " in the same form, or image" . Man sees , God see , Man hears, God hear, and so on. and the adjectives are according to the owner : the sight of Almighty is not like that of any other creature, he is البصير , Albaseer, the all seeing. and so on for any other adjectives.

Comment: And again, in such delicate subject, at least a question should be made to a qualified scholar, not on a forum, where all the qualification is reduced to a username and a password.

Answer (score -1):

Peace! The Bible is the words of God, unfortunately it has been tampered with by mankind. The Qu'ran is the words of God, that hasn't been tampered with which makes it an Holy Qu'ran. In this book there is no doubt in it. Being the Holy Qu'ran stands on truth ,it ables us to verify the truth in Bible by the scriptures in the Qu'ran. Both books when describing God they use the soft pronoun He meaning male or man. We are made in his image & the likeness of God. Man is the Khalifa of the earth giving power & dominion over the sea fish etc....
God is not spooky he is real. We have three forms liquid, gas,or solid.
If He was a spirit we would be spirits but we're not we are solid made in his image & likeness . They say the greatest trick the devil ever pulled off was making people think he doesn't exist. For me the greatest trick was hiding the reality of God!
I'm a believer & my God is not no mystery God. My God is presence in the world today. In Muslim world when the Mahdi is to return are you looking for a spirit or a man. In the Christian when the Messiah is to return are you looking for a spirit or a man. Not just any man but an extraordinary man. Why do we await the Mahdi & the Messiah come in the form of a man, because man and woman has been degraded ,man and woman is not man & woman they're beast in human form. Man & woman has been degenerated . This is fallen man & fallen woman, you don't know resurrected man ,you don't know elevated man ,you don't know man made in the likeness of God, you don't know original man, so therefore you would have to get acquainted with yourself by God sending one to you in your own form ,thats mighty in power ,mighty in wisdom, not only carrying the light but is the light! Then you can get an idea of who you are if you could only recognize who he is!
Prophet Muhammed (pbuh) said it wasn't me he slew them it was Allah in him that slew them.
If God is so close he closer than your jugular vein he has to be in you.
That's our higher self & our lower self is of satan .
The real jihad (Holy war) is I'm us. We fighting ourselves everyday battling right and wrong.
Let be real and stop mixing truth with falsehood. Allah built the earth on truth! We must stand on truth.
Satan world is on its way out and if you're a believer you know the God is love love win the fight every time.
The Earth belongs to the Righteous!
Peace!

Answer (score -2):

Brother yes you are right in saying that nothing is alike God neither man nor anything else. But there is a hadith that you should know. God created man in the form of the Most Merciful. ﺍِﻥَّ ﺍﻟﻠَّﻪَ ﺧَﻠَﻖَ ﺍﻟْﺎِﻧْﺴَﺎﻥَ ﻋَﻠَﻰ ﺻُﻮﺭَﺓِ ﺍﻟﺮَّﺣْﻤَﻦِ.  See, Bukhari, Isti’dhan, 1; Muslim, Birr, 115; Janna, 28; Musnad, ii, 244, 251, 315, 323, 434,
463, 519. Please read the link in my answer above. The fifth mystery part you should read.  This is very delicate so I am not here to just dispute but make the subject clear. Because saying it is not a hadith even if it was a hadith is very dangerous. So just read the 5th mystery part in Flashes  Book in 14th Flash.

Comment: If you take a look at your Post you may find at bottom left an "edit" link so instead of posting a new answer you could have edited your first answer!